# Extract text between paragraph tag using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I try to extract text between parapgraph tag using RegExp in javascript. But it doen't work...

My pattern:

```
<p>(.*?)</p>
```

Subject:

```
<p> My content. </p> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJ9ylGJ4SDyl49VGh9Q9an2vruuMip-VIIEG38DgGM3GvxEi_H"> <p> Second sentence. </p>
```

Result :

```
My content
```

What I want:

```
My content. Second sentence.
```

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/361684)

Comment: You can get the body of `<p>` tags just fine with regex (despite the warnings against parsing generally with it), but if you're using JavaScript there's no need to since you have `document.getElementsByTagName("p")`.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard - `document.getElementsByTagName()` is a DOM method.  It is only available to JavaScript because the browser provides it.  With node.js, there is no browser, and node.js does not natively parse HTML into a DOM.  You can't assume that, just because you are using the JavaScript language, a browser DOM is available.  A DOM can be made available to node.js if such a package is installed, such as [jsdom](https://npmjs.org/package/jsdom).

Comment: @gilly3 Ah, I see. Was not aware of that.

Comment: @gilly3, hoh no... Not that easy generic answer again -_-. Using regex for what he wants is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc - What about this valid html: `<p>Paragraph1<p>Paragaph2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "capture all group matches" (analogous to PHP's `preg_match_all`) in JavaScript, but you can cheat by using `.replace`:

```
var matches = [];
html.replace(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g, function () {
    //arguments[0] is the entire match
    matches.push(arguments[1]);
});
```

Comment: Ok so, how can I do using Jade and NodeJS for extract the text between <p> and </p>?

Comment: @tonymx227 I don't really know what you mean .. that code is just raw JavaScript, so you should be able to use it with any JS interpreter

Comment: Yes I know. But with controller I send to my Jade view (for example) all the posts, with my view I try to get the content of a post without tag... ${posts.content.match('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g')} but it doesn't work...

Comment: I don't know how to use Jade views, so I wouldn't really be able to help you there.  I said to use `.replace`, not `match`, though

Comment: I asked a new question because it's not the same subject. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @kilianc you could use `[\w\W]` instead of `.` for that or the `s` / dotall flag

Answer (score 1):

To get more than one match of a pattern the global flag `g` is added.
The `match` method ignores capture groups `()` when matching globally, but the `exec` method does not. See [MDN exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

```
var m,
    rex = /<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g,
    str = '<p> My content. </p> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJ9ylGJ4SDyl49VGh9Q9an2vruuMip-VIIEG38DgGM3GvxEi_H"> <p> Second sentence. </p>';

while ( ( m = rex.exec( str ) ) != null ) {
    console.log( m[1] );
}

//  My content. 
//  Second sentence.
```

If there may be newlines between the paragraphs, use `[\s\S]`, meaning *match any space or non-space character*, instead of `.`.

Note that this kind of regex will fail on nested paragraphs as it will match up to the first closing tag.

Comment: There's no such thing as "nested paragraphs".  A `<p>` does not require a closing tag.  A block element that occurs after an open `<p>` tag implies a closing `</p>` tag. Your regexp will treat multiple paragraphs without closing tags as one single paragraph.

Comment: @gilly3.  XHTML requires the closing tag and I think the OP makes it quite clear in his question he is looking for the content between opening and closing p tags. It is pretty obvious my answer assumes the closing tags and if there isn't any _the OP's_ regex (not mine) won't match anyway. Nevertheless, I think your observation is worthwhile, so thank you.