# Extracting text between paragraph tag in a Jade view

Tags: node.js, pug, express

I try to extract text between paragraph tag in a Jade view but it doesn't work.

My subject:

```
<p> My content. </p> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJ9ylGJ4SDyl49VGh9Q9an2vruuMip-VIIEG38DgGM3GvxEi_H"> <p> Second sentence. </p>
```

Jade view:

```
- var content = post.content.slice('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g');
p #{content}
```

Result:

```
<
```

Comment: I think it is the regexp, try this one: <p>(.*?)</p>

Comment: And why are you posting the same wuestion twice??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969810/extract-text-between-paragraph-tag-using-regex

Comment: No, same thing... Because I made a mistake on my precedent post... It's with Jade and NodeJS not only with Javascript.

Comment: Well, in your other post, @Explosion Pills was correct. The regexp is /<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g. You only need to remove the quotes. Plus, you will need the function provided in the other post.

Comment: post.content.split(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g); //extract all the sentence, it doesn't work.

Comment: Split is not what you want actually. Just make a custom function that uses @Explosion Pills's answer.

Comment: I can't make a custom function in my view, it's a Jade view, I just can use Javascript function.

Comment: If you are using express 3 it is easy as: app.locals.myHelper= function(valid, regex){ return "aaww yea"}

Comment: Yes I use Express 3. app.locals.myHelper but where? In the configure function?

Comment: It needs to be before you render your view. So yes, the app.configure(function(){...}) function seems good.

Comment: app.locals.getTextFromContent = function(content){
        var tab = content.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g);
        return tab.join('');
    }

Comment: Code above doesn't work.

Comment: - console.log(getTextFromContent(post.content));

Comment: Error: Read post Cannot call method 'join' of null

Comment: Why dont you use the code by @Explosion Pills in your other post.

Comment: Because I don't want to replace, I want to extract and get the text between paragraph tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do u need to extract text between paragraph tag on server side??

that will be something we do on client side js

---

in your case, `context` should be a parameter you pass to jade view, by `res.render('view', {context : "My content."})` or `res.locals`

so you can deal with your `#{context}` in Jade view

if you want to declare variable `context` in Jade view

it should be like

> -var context= "My content."
>
> p #{content}

---

#### reply to `jsdom` code

in your code

`posts[i]` is undefined.

I suppose u want to iterate posts, so you should use a `iterator` here

you can use `async` module here

in this case, `map` is very suitable

see here for document -> [async map](https://github.com/caolan/async#maparr-iterator-callback)

```
Creation.findAll({where: "state = 1",order: 'id DESC', limit: 2}).success(function(creations) {
    Post.findAll({where: "state = 1",order: 'id DESC', limit: 2}).success(function(posts){

async.map(posts, function(postEntity, callback){
jsdom.env(
            postEntity.content,
            ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
            function(errors, window) {
                //deal with errors
                if(errors) return callback(errors);

                postEntity.content = window.$("p").text();
                callback(null, postEntity);
            }
        );
}, function(err, transformedPosts){
    if(err) return callback(err);
    res.render('index', {
        creations: creations,
        posts: transformedPosts,
        title: "Anthony Cluse | Portfolio"
    });
});

    
});
});
```

FYI, you should use control flow library to manage your callback code

otherwise, it would be really hard to maintain

I recommend `async`

Comment: I need to get the text between paragraph tag because I have two views for my posts, the "posts" view with all the posts and the "post" view with a specific post. In the "posts" view, I would like to get a short description from the content, and in the "post" view, I get the content with tags....

Comment: you don't have to use extract.    
in the "posts" view with all the posts, after u query for the posts from DB, you can use substr like `string.substr(0, 10)` to get short description and send as a parameter to jade view. in the "post" view, you just query for a specific post from DB, and it's done. why use exact?

Comment: Yea, I use substr() function too, but if I don't remove tags, it's look like this "<p>Beginner of my senten..."!

Comment: you query your posts from DB? why do you have tag in that?

Comment: Yes from DB. Because I use tags in my textarea, I format posts myself.

Comment: ok I see...  you should use a dom parser module instead of extract by yourself. that will be easier and more flexible! try this -> [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom)

Comment: Ok, I tried with jsdom, you can see above. But it doesn't work. Maybe, I didn't use it properly.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'content' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;
Creation.findAll({where: "state = 1",order: 'id DESC', limit: 2}).success( function(creations) {
    Post.findAll({where: "state = 1",order: 'id DESC', limit: 2}).success(function(posts){
        console.log(posts[i].content);
        jsdom.env(
            posts[i].content,
            ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
            function(errors, window) {
                posts[i].content = window.$("p").text();
            }
        );
        i++;
        res.render('index', {
            creations: creations,
            posts: posts,
            title: "Anthony Cluse | Portfolio"
        });
    });
});
```